How do I prevent a specific external device (e.g. keyboard) on Mac from controlling the volume?
The volume control wheel on my keyboard seems to be broken. It randomly keeps changing the volume on its own. Is there a way I can prevent the keyboard from adjusting the volume while maintaining everything else working as usual?
